# How to get major Safari 10 version number with Selenium 3.3.1?

Tags: java, macos, selenium, safari, version

I'm developing a Java tool to automate Safari 10.x on MacOS Sierra using Selenium 3.3.1.
My code to create SafariDriver and get Safari version is as below:

```
DesiredCapabilities createCap = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
// some more options
WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver(createCap);
// do other tasks
//....
// try several ways to get version (displayed on About dialog is 10.0.1 (12602.2.14.x)
Capabilities newCap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
System.out.println("Version: " + newCap.getVersion());  

Object capVersion = newCap.getCapability("version");
System.out.println("Other way: " + capVersion.toString());
```

The result of above 2 methods are just "12602.2.14.x".

How can I get the exact version "10.0.1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using following:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return navigator.userAgent",""));
```

You'll get a String ; in which you can pinpoint your browser details and extract it.